# How to teach my child my profession in the guild 2?

Tags: guild-2

My son has become of age, there are many options to teach him, but I want him to take over the business, this option is not in the list.

I decided to teach him my self (it's written that I can do that), but how can I

teach my son? Do I need to go to the hut and teach him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that if you 'Cancel' the child will stay at home and learn his parent profession.

This will still cost money (unsure how much).